# What are functional-programming ways of implementing Conway's Game of Life

Tags: functional-programming

I recently [implemented](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/108084/deploy/conway/index.html) for fun [Conway's Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#Rules) in Javascript (actually coffeescript but same thing). Since javascript can be used as a functional language I was trying to stay to that end  of the spectrum. I was not happy with my results. I am a fairly good OO programmer and my solution smacked of same-old-same-old. So long question short: what is the (pseudocode) functional style of doing it?

Here is Pseudocode for my attempt:

```
class Node
  update: (board) ->
    get number_of_alive_neighbors from board
    get this_is_alive from board
    if this_is_alive and number_of_alive_neighbors < 2 then die
    if this_is_alive and number_of_alive_neighbors > 3 then die
    if not this_is_alive and number_of_alive_neighbors == 3 then alive

class NodeLocations
  at: (x, y) -> return node value at x,y
  of: (node) -> return x,y of node

class Board
  getNeighbors: (node) -> 
   use node_locations to check 8 neighbors 
   around node and return count

nodes = for 1..100 new Node
state = new NodeState(nodes)
locations = new NodeLocations(nodes)
board = new Board(locations, state)

executeRound:
  state = clone state
  accumulated_changes = for n in nodes n.update(board)
  apply accumulated_changes to state
  board = new Board(locations, state)
```

Comment: Oblig: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9xAKttWgP4

Comment: @Oded that is depressingly over my head. I recognize the basic concepts but only just barely

Comment: Way over my head too... I just posted it as an example of what a master of a specialized language can do. Call it an inspiration for us all :)

Comment: @GeorgeMauer "actually coffeescript but same thing" this is sad day

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, a couple of ideas. I'm not an expert in FP, but...

It's fairly clear we should have a type `Board` which represents a game state. The basis of the implementation should be an `evolve` function of type `evolve :: Board -> Board`; meaning it produces a `Board` from applying the rules of the game to a `Board`.

How should we implement `evolve`? A `Board` should probably be an n x m matrix of `Cell`s. We could implement a function `cellEvolve` of type `cellEvolve :: Cell -> [Cell] -> Cell` which given a `Cell` and its neighboring `Cell`s calculates the `Cell` state in the next iteration.

We should also implement a `getCellNeighbors` function which extracts a `Cell`s neighbors from a `Board`. I'm not entirely sure of the signature of this method; depending on how you implement `Cell` and `Board` you could have for instance `getCellNeighbors :: Board -> CoordElem -> CoordElem -> [Cell]`, which given a Board and two coordinates (`CoordElem` would be the type used to index positions in a `Board`), gives you a variable length list of the neighbors (not all cells in the board have the same number of neighbors- corners have 3 neighbors, borders 5 and everyone else, 8).

`evolve` can thus be implemented by combining `cellEvolve` and `getCellNeighbors` for all cells in the board, again the exact implementation will depend on how you implement `Board` and `Cell`, but it should be something like "for all cells in the current board, get their neighbors and use them to calculate the new board's corresponding cell'. This should be possible to do with a generic application of those functions over the whole board using a "map over board's cell function".

Other thoughts:

- You should really implement `cellEvolve` so that it takes as a parameter a type `GameRules` which encodes the rules of the game- say a list of tuples `(State,[(State,NumberOfNeighbors)],State)` which says for a given state and the number of neighbors in each state, which should be the state in the next iteration. `cellEvolve`'s signature could then be `cellEvolve :: GameRules -> Cell -> [Cell] -> Cell`
- This would logically take you to making `evolve :: Board -> Board` turn into `evolve :: GameRules -> Board -> Board`, so that you could use `evolve` unchanged with different `GameRules`, but you could go a step further and make `cellEvolve` pluggable instead of `GameRules`.
- Playing with `getCellNeighbors` you could also make `evolve` generic with regards to the `Board`'s topology- you could have `getCellNeighbors` which wrap around either board's edges, 3d boards, etc.

Answer (score 10):

If you're writing a functional programming version of Life you owe it to yourself to learn about Gosper's Algorithm. It uses ideas from functional programming to achieve *trillions* of generations per second on boards *trillions* of squares on a side. That sounds impossible I know, but it is thoroughly possible; I have a nice little implementation in C# that easily handles square boards 2^64 squares on a side.

The trick is to take advantage of the massive self-similarlity of Life boards across both time and space. By memoizing the future state of large sections of the board you can rapidly advance huge sections at once.

I've been meaning to blog a beginners introduction to Gosper's Algorithm for many years now, but I have never had the time. If I end up doing so, I'll post a link here.

Note that you want to look up [Gosper's Algorithm for Life computations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashlife), not the Gosper's Algorithm for computing hypergeometric sums.

Comment: looks interesting - still waiting for that link though... ;)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at the implementations on [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) for inspiration.

For example there are functional Haskell and OCaml versions which create a new board each turn by applying a function to the previous one, while the graphical OCaml version uses two arrays and updates them alternately for speed.

Some of the implementations decompose the board *update* function into functions for *counting* the neighbourhood, applying the *life rule* and *iterating* over the board. Those seem like useful components to base a functional design on. Try modifying only the board, keeping everything else as pure functions.

Answer (score 3):

Nice coincidence, we covered this exact problem in our Haskell lecture today.  First time I've seen it but here is a link to the source code we were given:

http://pastebin.com/K3DCyKj3

Comment: would you mind explaining more on what it does and why do you recommend it as answering the question asked? ["Link-only answers"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info "what's this") are not quite welcome at Stack Exchange

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short purely functional version in Clojure. All credit goes to Christophe Grand who published this in his blog post: [Conway’s Game of Life](http://clj-me.cgrand.net/2011/08/19/conways-game-of-life/)

```
(defn neighbours [[x y]]
  (for [dx [-1 0 1] 
        dy (if (zero? dx) [-1 1] [-1 0 1])]
    [(+ dx x) (+ dy y)]))

(defn step [cells]
  (set (for [[loc n] (frequencies (mapcat neighbours cells))
             :when (or (= n 3) (and (= n 2) (cells loc)))]
         loc)))
```

The game can then be played by repeatedly applying the "step" function to a set of cells, e.g.:

```
(step #{[1 0] [1 1] [1 2]})
=> #{[2 1] [1 1] [0 1]}
```

The cleverness is the (mapcat neighbours cells) part - what this does is create a list of eight neighbours for each of the active cells and concatenates them all together. Then the number of times each cell appears in this list can be counted with (frequencies ....) and finally the ones that have the right frequency counts make it through to the next generation.